# Paypal statuses in Magento

Tags: php, magento, paypal

We're facing a problem with paypal in ou Magento Shop (CE 1.7)

Here is the history of our statuses :

-Pending Payment
-Payment verification
-Payment refused by Paypal

But when the payment is refused by paypal, it creates an invoice, then a creditmemo. I don't want this, when the invoice is created, it ask our team to ship the order but this order do not need to be shipped.

How to avoid creating the invoice, or when creating the invoice having a param that stop my shipping process.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Out-of-the-box Magento requires an invoice to make online payment authorization (or capture), that is to make a request to PayPal and try to charge customer. You should not rely on invoices when shipping orders. In Magento you should use order status instead.

Comment: In fact we Observe invoicing to send order to our Management Software.

But we do not yet Observe creditmemo to mark as cancelled orders in our Software.

So I need to find out where in the code, the cancellation create the invoice, to add an extra param to say "Do Not Send To ERP". Dunno if you see what I mean.